# How to replace (in the most convenient way) all attributes with a given name in an xml file?

Tags: xml, xslt, lxml

Supposed that I have some xml input which contains something like this. Where `w15` maybe other things like `w`, `w1`.

```
<w15:presenceInfo w15:providerId="None" w15:userId="First Last"/>
```

Does anybody know what is the best way to make the replacement?

w15:userId="First Last" -> w15:userId="Something else"

I don't want to use things like `sed` as I am afraid to replace something that is not supposed to replace.

Does anybody know a solution in xslt?

Does anybody know a solution in lxml (http://lxml.de/)?

Any other solutions not using xslt/lxml?

Which one is the best for solving this problem? (With `sed`, it is just one line to replace "First Last" with "Something else" (suppose that there is nothing in the input `xml` file that would not make `sed` not working.) Is there a solution that respects `xml` spec but as simple as one line code?

Answer (score 2):

In XSLT 3.0 it gets reasonably close to the one-liner you are looking for:

```
<xsl:transform version="3.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*:userId[.='First Last']">
    <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">Something else</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with the good news. You can replace value of an attribute with
particular name, regardless of the namespace, using a template matching an
attribute (`@*`) with particular `local-name()` in the predicate.

The script given below has 2 such templates, for `providerId` and `userId`.

But the bad news is that you can not totally "close eyes" to the namespaces
used. Rules concerning namespace processing by XSLT require that the XSLT
script must containt definitions of all used namespaces.

Note that the script below contains such a definition: `xmlns:w15="urn:dummy_15"`, usually placed in the root tag of the script.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:w15="urn:dummy_15">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*[local-name() = 'providerId']">
    <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
      <xsl:value-of select="'Something else 1'"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*[local-name() = 'userId']">
    <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
      <xsl:value-of select="'Something else 2'"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

For a working example see http://xsltransform.net/gVrtEmW

So you can have a "sample" XSLT script, without namespaces, but in the last
moment, before actual running of the script, you have to take a look at
what namespaces contains your source XML file and add specifications of used
namespaces to the script.